# Stretch twitter bootstrap table cell across entire table for description

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to format the first row of my table using twitter bootstrap html/css to stretch across all the table headers so that I can use it as a description - like the row with bold font reading "Build Agency Leader Characteristics to Support..." in the image below. When I use td with custom widths, or try to drop text directly into the table row, it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - just had to add attribute colspan=5 to a new table header.